# i dont get what this means CS0120 C# An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property

Tags: c#, move

What is wrong with this code?

I just want to move an object left to right; is there a better way?

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class test : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float speed = 5f;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () 
   {
       // no-op 
   }

    //Update is called once per frame
    void Update () 
    {
        Transform.Translate(speed,0f,0f);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`UnityEngine.Transform.Translate()`](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.Translate.html) is an instance method, but you are calling it as if it's static.

[`MonoBehaviour` has a `transform`](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Component-transform.html) property which I suspect is what you're looking for -- a bit confusing as it's lowercase (which is also an unusual convention for C#). Change the line to use the (lowercase) `transform` property:

```
void Update () {
    transform.Translate(speed,0f,0f);
}
```

Comment: i cant seem to get it to work when i do that...what i want to do is make a rigidbody move across the floor to the right